# React Native Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: react-native

I am building a react native app without expo and am running into an error when running the command "react-native run-ios". Metro bundler reports an ENOENT error since the bundler is seemingly looking in a directory one level up from the projects root directory and therefore can not find the necessary modules.

I have already tried restarting the bundler, my computer, the ios simulator, and updated packages

Here is the specific error message after running  "react ntive run ios"

```
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2 

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/matt/Bettersleep/assets/images'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:806:3)
    at Object.getDirFiles (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:103:34)
    at Map.AssetResolutionCache.dirPath [as _factory] (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/AssetResolutionCache.js:41:36)
    at Map.get (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/lib/MapWithDefaults.js:23:24)
    at AssetResolutionCache.resolve (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/AssetResolutionCache.js:91:43)
    at resolveAsset (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:229:36)
    at resolveAssetFiles (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:463:22)
    at resolveFile (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:349:20)
    at resolveFileOrDir (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:262:22)
    at resolveModulePath (/Users/matt/Bettersleep/model2/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:184:18)
```

I have previously been able to build a project and this new issue popped up after adding the firebase sdk to the project. I have seen other ENOENT errors but none seem to deal with a packager searching in the wrong directory for files.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, delete you node_modules and app from simulator. Then re-install everything back, clear cache and see if it start bundler from root directory.

Before doing that, you can try 'react-native start' from you root directory. For some reason it helps me with a same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was as simple as navigating into the correct directory. Turns out I was trying to start RN from a parent directory that didn't have the correct files.